# Prove that dim[(span$(v_1 + w,...,v_m + w)] \geq m - 1. $

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $v_1,...,v_m$ is linearly independent in  $V$ and  $w \in V. $ Prove that dim[(span$(v_1 + w,...,v_m + w)] \geq m - 1. $

attempt: Let $v_1,...,v_m$ be linear independent. So there is $a_1,..,a_m \in F,$ such that  $a_1v_1 + .... + a_mv_m = 0$. where $a_1=...=a_m = 0.$

Then $(v_1 - v_2,...,v_{m-1} - v_m)$ span and are linear independent in $V$. And dim$span (v_1,...,v_m) = m.$

Can someone please help me? I am stuck.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your first line in your attempt seems to have something backwards, independent mean there are no such constants (other than 0,0,0,0,0,0...)

Also I have no idea how you are getting this spanning conclusion or the independence, as it's not at all clear how it follows from your givens. Consider expanding some details there.

Comment: I dont really know how to continue. I did an exercise before and showed $v_1 - v_2,...,v_{m-1} - v_m$ was linearly independent and that it spanned a vector space V , whenever, $v_1,...,v_m$ are linearly independent.  So i thought of using it.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Show the span contains $v_1-v_2$, $\dots,v_1-v_m$, and show these vectors are linearly independent.